# Characterization of the complex unit ball?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Take $U\subsetneq \mathbb{K}$ open neighborhood of zero verifying:

1. $U=U^2 =\{uv\,:\,u,v\in U\}$;
2. $U=-U$;
3. $\mbox{int}(\mbox{cl}(U))=U$;
4. $1\in \mbox{cl}(U)$.

I conjecture that $U$ is actually $U(0,1)$, the open unit ball in $\mathbb{K}$.

Taking $U$ as union of its connected components proves the real case, but for the complex this only leads to the fact that $U$ must be connected (which is nice, but not enough). Also, it's quite easy to see that $U\subset U(0,1)$.

It seems to me that the main problem is that using $4.$ we have some $(a_n)_n\subset U$ converging to one, but we don't control how it converges when working on complex numbers.

EDIT. Clarification: $U^2=U\,U=\{uv\,:\,u,v\in U\}$

Comment: $-0.5\in U(0,1)\setminus U(0,1)^2$ for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually $-0.5 = (-\sqrt{0.5}) \sqrt{0.5} \in U(0,1)^2$

Comment: Oh, you meant that. Sorry, I thought $U^2=\{u^2|u\in U\}$.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for a proper regular open multiplicative subsemigroup of $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) containing $0$, which has $1$ in its closure, is closed under multiplication by $-1$ and in which any element can be written as a product of two other elements.